# Status Bar Color on navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I have applied the following. So when the navigation drawer is opened, the status bar color looks black.But where is my problem? It is coloring the whole width of the status bar, I want him to color just until the part the navigation drawer is open.How can I work this out?

> ```
>     <style name="AppBaseTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
>     <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/pink</item>
>     <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/pink</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pink</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pink</item>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
>     <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
>     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <!-- We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar -->
>     <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
>     <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
>     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
>     </style>
> ```

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3Q0tDQ3Z1OHg5VHc/patterns_navdrawer_elevation1.png like this, first part of status bar is transparent the part after navigation drawer stays pink

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```